# PyCharm Always Executing but Never Finishing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I just started using PyCharm; I used Spyder for the past several years.

I'm testing the sample code from here:

https://pythonprogramming.net/k-means-titanic-dataset-machine-learning-tutorial/

All I'm doing is reading in data from an Excel file and printing the data in the Console window.  In Spyder, this would take about 1 second and you would see the results in the Console window.  In PyCharm, I see 'Executing Code in Console', as a Background Task, and it runs and runs and runs, but it never really does anything.  Is there some kind of setting that can actually get the code to execute?  PyCharm seems to be starting something but it never actually finishes what it starts.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code here. Otherwise it is a shot in the dark of what might be happening

Comment: Just testing some sample code that I found online.  I want to get it working and then customize it to my specific needs.

Comment: i think you need to change the configuration for running that code, uncheck/check `execute terminal on output console`

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  Thanks a lot!!